# Converting List to Dataframe, then Appending

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append

I am trying to convert a list into a DataFrame. The list is from a document where words are split individually into individual lines. The list then needs to be converted into a DataFrame. However after I run my for loop, the DataFrame contains no information.

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt')

wordlist = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1'])

for line in data:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
            wordlist.append({'col1': word}, ignore_index=True)
```

The words are split correctly:

```
b'The'
b'following'
b'are'
b'the'
b'graphical'
b'(non-control)'
b'characters'
```

However the appended dataframe Returns:

```
print(wordlist)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it splits directly from data:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt')

wordlist = pd.DataFrame(data.read().split(), columns = ['col1'])
```

output:

```
             col1
0          b'The'
1    b'following'
2          b'are'
3          b'the'
4    b'graphical'
..            ...
853      b'SMALL'
854     b'LETTER'
855          b'Y'
856       b'WITH'
857  b'DIAERESIS'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong syntax

```
for line in data:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
            wordlist = wordlist.append({'col1': word}, ignore_index=True)
```